# How to make a continuous 360deg animation of a list about the Y-Axis in WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I am completely new to animations in WPF/XAML. Below is code I found here on SO to rotate a 2D list around the Y-axis.

However, it appears as though only rotation through the left quadrant is occurring and then it disappears for a time before reappearing again in the same quadrant.

What do I need to do to visualize a complete 360deg ***continuous*** rotation about the Y-Axis (without it disappearing).

Thank you for any help.

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Background="White">
            <DockPanel.Resources>
                <!-- UI Mesh -->
                <MeshGeometry3D x:Key="uiMesh" TriangleIndices="0,1,2 3,4,5" 
                        Positions="-1,-1,2 1,-1,2 1,1,2 1,1,2 -1,1,2 -1,-1,2 "
                        TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 1,0, 0,0 0,1"/>
                <!-- UI Mesh Rotation -->
                <Storyboard x:Key="uiSpin" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:02"   
                                 Storyboard.TargetName="uiRotate" 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="360"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </DockPanel.Resources>

            <DockPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource uiSpin}"/>
                </EventTrigger>
            </DockPanel.Triggers>

            <Viewport3D>
                <!-- Camera -->
                <Viewport3D.Camera>
                    <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4"/>
                </Viewport3D.Camera>

                <!-- Button on 3D -->
                <Viewport2DVisual3D >
                    <!-- Give the plane a slight rotation -->
                    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                        <RotateTransform3D>
                            <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                                <AxisAngleRotation3D x:Name="uiRotate" 
                                                 Angle="40" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                            </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        </RotateTransform3D>
                    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>

                    <!-- The Geometry, Material, and Visual for the 
                     Viewport2DVisual3D -->
                    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
                                    TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" 
                                    TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
                    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                    <!-- Setup the Material"
                     You can use any material you want.  For the material 
                     that you want to have the Visual be placed on, you simply 
                     need to set the Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial 
                     attached property to true.
                -->
                    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" 
                                     Brush="White"/>
                    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

                    <Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
                        <!-- The 2D UI-->
                        <ListBox 
                          Name="listBox1"
                          PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="listBox1_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Converter={cv:InverseBooleanConverter}}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Printers}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Printer}"
                          ItemsPanel="{StaticResource VSP}"/>
                    </Viewport2DVisual3D.Visual>
                </Viewport2DVisual3D>

                <!-- Lights -->
                <ModelVisual3D>
                    <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                        <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
                    </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                </ModelVisual3D>
            </Viewport3D>

        </DockPanel>
```

Comment: I don't have time at the moment to look at the code, but...have you tried using an ambient light instead of directional? With the 3D API, sometimes, a "things disappear" problem is due to the simple lack of any illumination that would produce an image. The other common error, of course, being that the triangles are facing the wrong way (you can double-check that by adding a backface material...use a gaudy color so it's obvious when you're looking at the back of the triangle).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I do not know what a "backface material" is, but strongly suspect that is the problem. In playing with the AxisAngelRotation3D, the material disappears between 90 and 360deg. (I can find next to no information on this).  Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm...well, I was thinking about https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.media3d.geometrymodel3d.backmaterial, but on second look I see above you're using `Viewport2DVisual3D`, which I don't have any real experience with. I don't really know how the "2D in 3D" stuff works; it's possible that you can only ever see one side of the 2D element, and that it's intended to be placed on the face of a solid where the back would be obscured. You could try mirroring the 2D element (the `ListBox`) on the reverse face and see if that helps.

Comment: Of course, make sure you also try an ambient light, just in case that's the only thing wrong. In any case, you should **definitely** fix your question so it includes a proper [mcve]. Eliminate everything that's not strictly necessary, _add_ the minimal amount of code for an actual runnable program, and maybe someone else will have time to play around with the code and get it to work like you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I really did include this as a "minimal reproducible example". This comes almost exactly from [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37371/Viewport-DVisual-D) by Sacha Barber with substitution of a list for his buttons.  What is a "backface material"?  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ooops!  Sorry, just read your link to backface matieral. I think that maybe my problem....

Comment: _"I really did include this as a "minimal reproducible example""_ -- no, not really. Please read [mcve]. I won't pick apart the entire thing, but just as an example, the entire `ListBox` declaration in XAML relies on a whole slew of entities that are not present anywhere in the code above. See also [ask], and especially read the articles that are linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: As far as the backface material goes, as I noted it's possible that's not an option when you're using `Viewport2DVisual3D`. The `BackMaterial` property is on the `Geometry3D` class, so you would be able to set it for the `MeshGeometry3D` that you've defined for the `Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry`, but I'm not sure whether that would change how the `ListBox` itself is presented; it may be that the `ListBox` would still not be visible, even though you can make the backface of the geometry its being displayed on visible. Still, worth a try I guess.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "AmbientLight" is a good idea...but sadly did not make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on @PeterDuniho suggestions led to the following article:[Flippable 3D List Items in WPF](http://interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/17/wpf-flippable-3D-list)   by Ian Griffiths in Weblog Form (RSS 2.0). This was a great study into the "BackMaterial" mentioned by @PeterDuniho. However, I did not want the "jump" which Griffiths has in is code. I find the current resolution of Viewport2DVisual3D to be more then adequate. Reading the articles by Josh Smith on Viewport2DVisual3D     [Introducing ContentControl3D](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/02/23/introducing-contentcontrol3d/) was tremendously helpful. Finaly,  [seeing the back of the Viewport2DVisual3D](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/52e4c43f-85f8-4e03-903d-3e7c1c60d117/seeing-the-back-of-the-viewport2dvisual3d) by needbrew helped me to better understand the Viewport2DVisual3D. There are many other papers discussing Geometry3D, but relatively few on Viewport2DVisual3D, I don't know why.

In any event, for other novices like me, I post below a working continuous 360deg rotation of a  button (not a list @PeterDuniho :) ) done with Viewport2DVisual3D. This is a near reprint of needbrew's solution, as referenced above.

```
<Window x:Class="TestV3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestV3"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <!-- UI Mesh Rotation -->
        <Storyboard x:Key="uiSpin" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:15" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="uiRotate" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="360"/>
            <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:15" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="uiRotate2" 
                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="360"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </DockPanel.Resources>

    <DockPanel.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource uiSpin}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </DockPanel.Triggers>

    <ScrollBar Name="horz" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal"
Minimum="-180" Maximum="180"
LargeChange="10" SmallChange="1" />
    <Viewport3D>

        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="0, 0, 4"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <!-- Button on 3D -->
        <Viewport2DVisual3D>
            <!-- Give the plane a slight rotation -->
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D  x:Name="uiRotate" Angle="{Binding 
   ElementName=horz, Path=Value}" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>

            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>

            <!-- The Geometry, Material, and Visual for the Viewport2DVisual3D -->
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
    TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

            <Button>Hello, 3D</Button>

        </Viewport2DVisual3D>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D>

            <!-- Give the plane a slight rotation -->
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D  x:Name="uiRotate2" Angle="{Binding ElementName=horz, Path=Value}" Axis="0, 1, 0" />
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Transform>

            <!-- The Geometry, Material, and Visual for the Viewport2DVisual3D -->

            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="-1,1,0 -1,-1,0 1,-1,0 1,1,0"
  TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 2 1 0 3 2"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>

            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True" Brush="White"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>

            <Button>Hello, 3D back>
                <Button.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1" ScaleY="-1"/>
                </Button.RenderTransform>
            </Button>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D>

        <!-- Lights -->
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <DirectionalLight Color="#FFFFFFFF" Direction="0,0,-1"/>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>

    </Viewport3D>

</DockPanel>
```